# In tmux, is there something similar to `monitor-activity` but for a single pane?

Tags: tmux

I use `bind m setw monitor-activity` so that I can easily toggle whether or not I want visual updates about when a window has updated. However, sometimes I'll have a window with panes which have updates I want to have notice about the moment it updates, and other panes which are constantly updating, but require no action. I would love to be able to toggle the monitor-activity for just one pane so that I can ignore the unhelpful updates, but I'm not sure how to set this up, or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After poking around some more on Google and reading man pages, I've determined that currently there is no feature that lets you monitor activity in a single pane, just windows. The best work around that I've found is the `monitor-content` option, which lets you give an fnmatch pattern match string for tmux to watch for. When a match is found, tmux can alert you in ways similar to `monitor-activity`. The only trick then becomes figuring out what the match string is that will alert you for just the content you care about.